# Location Manager not working in android 4.4.4

Tags: java, android, gps, location

Android amateur and first time posting here. 
I'm developing an app that get's the GPS location of the user and then sends to a Mysql database. On Android 7.1 (Samsung note 5) it works perfectly but when I try to use in Android 4.2.2 (Samsung J1) the location doesn't update.

Below my MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    final int INTERVAL = 0; /* milliseconds */
    final int DISTANCE = 0; /* meters */

    //after asking the user for permission
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        // to check if the request code is the same as we used, in this case 1
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            //if true, then it means we have the permission
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, INTERVAL, DISTANCE, locationListener); //every 15 seconds or 50 meters
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //change the title on action bar to have the name of the Bus
        setTitle("Bus 1 - CMC");

        mMap = googleMap;


        //add Marker at VM Head Offices - as we waiting for the current location to be updated
        LatLng maputo = new LatLng(-25.9758904,32.5805966);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(maputo).title("Vodacom Head Office"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(maputo, 15));

        //get the device location
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                isNetworkAvailable(MapsActivity.this);

                //for better accuracy
                int suitableMeter = 10; // adjust your need
                if (location.hasAccuracy()  && location.getAccuracy() <= suitableMeter) {
                    // This is your most accurate location.
                    //Updated last updated location time text
                    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    TextView textViewLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLastUpdated);
                    textViewLocation.setText("Location last updated: " + currentDateTimeString);


                    LatLng busLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                    //TODO
                    //check if user has internet connection, if not then show dialog and ask to activate it

                    //send data to database
                    sendLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), currentDateTimeString);

                    //clear the previous markers
                    mMap.clear();
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(busLocation).title("Current Location"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(busLocation, mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                switch (status) {
                    case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
    //                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS is available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS is out of Service.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS temporarily unavailable.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Provider is enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                //TODO show dialog or pop up to open
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Provider is disabled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

        //If device is running sdk<23 Marshmellow, no need to request permission
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, INTERVAL, DISTANCE, locationListener);
        } else  {
            // if don't have permission. ask for permission
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //ask for permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            } else {
                // we have permission
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, INTERVAL, DISTANCE, locationListener);
            }
        }
    }


    // To add the action bar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //  Responding to Android Action Bar Events
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.editBusName:
            Toast.makeText(this, "To create page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return(true);
        case R.id.reportBug:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportBug.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return(true);
        case R.id.aboutApp:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutApp.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return(true);
        case R.id.adminOptions:
            Toast.makeText(this, "To create page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return(true);
    }
        return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the Location setting set to high accuracy or GPS only on the Samsung J1?  Note that you are only requesting GPS location, so if you have the Location setting set to Power saving, your code won't get a location.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Try to request location updates using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` either with, or instead of GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting any error. The GPS is on, it works on google maps app.

Comment: When I use the fused provider it works but then it doesn't refresh the location time to time and it's not that accurate.